# xlog scale with pgfplots for random x-values

Tags: pgfplots

In the code below, two things should be modified:

1. xlabels and xgrid should appear for x=10^-0.1, x=10^0 and x=10^0.1 only
2. the grid along the x-axis should reflect the logarithmic scale (ie, not constant) with the major grid for the values listed above only

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,width=10cm}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,set decimal separator={,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[grid=both,enlarge x limits=false,scale only axis,width=8.5cm,height=6cm,ymin=1,ymax=1.5,tick style={draw=none}]
\addplot[color=black,mark=*,mark size=1pt]
coordinates{(0.666667,1.21982)(1.49206,1.19949)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the option `xtickten={-0.1,0,0.1}` does what you want for both, (1.) and (2.): it displays only the tick positions 10^-0.1, 10^0 and 10^0.1 and it only displays these grid lines.

Note that the grid should respect the logarithmic scale in any case (and it does so for -0.1, 0, and 0.1).

Comment: thanks it helps but it does not show the thin lines of the minor grid. How can I add them?

Comment: By default, pgfplots generates minor logarithmic grids only if the major ticks are of type j*10^j. Try out the `minor xtick={<positions>}` feature to provide some manually (requires a recent version I believe). Providing only the exponents base ten (like `xtickten`) is not possible here, however.

Comment: ok thanks. Will a new version of pfgplots handle logarithmic minor grid whatever the major scale is?

Comment: Such a feature is not yet planned.

Comment: alright. Maybe in a more long term future then.

Comment: I am wondering how to choose them automatically... I mean, for a "normal" log plot, you would place them between 10^i and 10^{i+1}, using j*10^i, j=1,...9. And that is actually how I read them. I have never seen minor log tick marks (or grid lines) with a different distance... would you divide into equally spaced intervals (using 10 ticks)?

Comment: I do not think j and i have to be integers here. You just want to show that data along a logarithmic scale are not linearly distributed (which is not shown by the major grid). So, your method 10^i and 10^{i+1}, using j*10^i, j=1,...9 would work for any other scale, 10^{-0.2}, 10^{-0.1}, 10^{0} and 10^{0.1} 10^{0.2} for instance.

Comment: You are right, that's probably the best way. However, I am in doubt if anyone can read that stuff (which is fairly simple in the integer case). But you are right in one point: it shows clearly the logarithmic character at first sight. I'll take that as feature request.

Comment: thanks (I'm not very good at requesting features on github-like systems).